# Firestore: update all where

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need to

> update "users" Firestore collection documents
>   whereEqualTo("somefield", true)

For many updates I think it could be **WriteBatch** with a lot of updates, but maybe there is another smart way to do this?
For example, if I need to update **10M(millions)** of users - it would be **OutOfMemoryException** on Android device.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the only way to achieve this is create cloud function for firestore which will get chunks of your data and then you can update a field you want.

Comment: can you provide example to do this with cloud functions and firestore?
I prefer to do it in **transaction** to be sure all of users updated, not partially

Comment: @android51130 It's not possible. You can do this with small database, but not with milions of objects.